# SSRS: textbox format hide complete row (group header)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I get a weird behavior formating a textbox in a group header. If the textbox is set to default shows the data, but so soon how set the format to percentage (or anything else) the complete row (group header) won't show.

With the textbox in default:
[image]

Set to percentage:
[image]

And will hide the complete row:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually changed the height of the row and it's working. I don't know if was problem with the screen high resolution (2560 x 1440), I saw similar issues with some windows in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Use Expression instead of format.

```
=Format(Fields!myFields.Value,"0.00")
```

Comment: I tried as 'Custom' format and also in the 'Properties' panel, but I get the same problem. I'm not sure where can I apply the expression. In the textbox I'm using a expression for calculate the value, can I add other one to set the format? How?

Comment: Of course, just apply format to the calculated value

Comment: yes, of course, stupid newbie question :/ whatever, the same effect

Comment: manually changed the height of the row and now it's working